# CRM Portal: WebAPI: Error while executing WebAPI request: Attribute {0} cannot be found for table {1}

Tags: crm, portal

I am getting this response back when trying to execute a WebAPI request, but can't figure out why its erroring out. Moreover the error is not very helpful, as it doesn't tell which entity or which field, and I cannot identify any fields missing.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "90040100",
    "message": "Attribute {0} cannot be found for table {1}.",
    "innererror": {
        "code": "90040100",
        "message": "Attribute {0} cannot be found for table {1}.",
        "type": "InvalidAttribute"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you configure the Portals Web API to include the attribute? can you post the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: Did you see this article? https://debajmecrm.com/call-custom-action-using-webapi-in-powerapps-portals-dynamics-365-portals/

Answer (score 1):

I tried this myself a few times but got the same errors that you describe here. According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/web-api-overview#web-api-operations) this is explicitly not supported.

> Calling **actions** and **functions** using the portals Web API is not supported.

[image: Screenshot of MS Documentation]